# OpensessionInViewInterceptor/Filter to handle multiple SessionFactories

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

We are developing a Multi-tenant application with having Separate Schema per tenant.

We are using one `SessionFactory` per each Schema which is working fine without using `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.

We want to use Spring `TransactionManager` along with `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.

We could find some references to customize OpenSessionInViewFilter to handle multiple `SessionFactories` (by overriding `lookupSessionFactory` method), but it is not working for us as we need to reference this Filter from our DAOs.

So we planned to go for `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` which can be accessible from other spring beans (DAOs), but not finding a way to customize it to lookup for `SessionFactory` based on TenantId.

We are using Hibernate 3.2.5 and Spring-2.5.6

Comment: why you need reference to Filter in DAO? will you explain a little

Comment: Hi, we have followed this link [[link]](http://cchweblog.wordpress.com/2009/10/10/using-opensessioninviewfilter-in-spring-web-application/) to implement OpenSessionInViewFilter and extended it to MultiTenantOSIVF by overriding its lookUpSessionFactory() method to return SessionFactory based on tenantId. And as you can see in HibernateUserDao class we need to call SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, Boolean.FALSE) we are trying to get sessionFactory by calling MultiTenantOpenSessionInViewFilter's lookUpSessionFactory() method,for this we need to have filter access in DAO.

Comment: Before trying separate sessionFactory for each tenant, we have tried SingleSessionFactory and switching datasources based on tenant id. Here we are facing issue with the same OpenSessionInViewFilter as SessionFactory does not have SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() which takes connection object as request parameter like SessionFactory.openSession(connection). Both approaches are working fine but when tried in conjuction with OpenSessionInViewFiler they are not…any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So, when you make SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, Boolean.FALSE) call are you getting error? can you post the error log if you are getting any. I will try to find a solution for your problem

Comment: @uma where do you keep the tenantId? is it available in your DAO classes?

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the filter in DAO you can define your filter as a bean and use  `DelegatingFilterProxy` to register this bean as a filter:

**bean definition:**

```
<bean id="openEntityManagerInViewFilter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter">
  <property name="entityManagerFactoryBeanName" value="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

**web.xml part:**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```